# Issue with different ways of powering

Tags: power, rfid

I have a project to make where I have to read tags out of 5 RFID Readers and when every tag is in correct reader to open a relay. The schematic is the same with [Annaane's](https://github.com/Annaane/MultiRfid/blob/master/Wiring.jpg) with the difference I have 5 Readers, so I didn't make one.
I also have made the board that i have attached so I can connect all the common pins together (MISO, MOSI, SCK, RESET, 3.3V and GND)

The SDA SS pins are connected directly to pins 3-7 of Arduino.
My code works just fine when powering arduino through my Laptop's USB port but since it have to be installed somewhere I tried the following ways to power it:

1. USB coming from a Xiaomi 5v Phone Charger to Arduino's USB port
2. USB coming from this to Arduino's USB Port. It is being powered from a 12v 1amp power supply from and old router.
3. The 12v 1amp power supply from and old router.
4. L7805CV and it's suggested circuit from the datasheet

My problem is that none of these ways seem to work properly. What I mean is that I cant get readings from the Readers as it should do. I have an LED which lights up when it read a tag but at these cases it only lights up only on some of the readers. The strange part is that when I am charging my laptop and powering arduino through its usb port it doesnt work either.

Any help please?

[image: This is the board underneath]
[image: From above]

Comment: On your board I see much of what seems to be flux residuals from soldering. Maybe you should clean that up. Depending on the flux, you might get unwanted connections there. I personally use the lighter fluid of my zippo.

Comment: This flux is there because I used to have a 5V regulator (L7805CV) but I desoldered it because id didnt seem to work properly. I dont think that this is the issue.

Comment: I am suspecting noise. Can you test once with a Power bank if you have access?